# Windows 7 Starter and Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot

I have an Aspire One netbook with 1GB RAM. I have Windows 7 starter, and I would like to try a double boot with Ubuntu. I know that it is possible to download it to a flash pen, but I was wondering if having both Starter and Ubuntu on my hard drive would make the computer super slow. I have no previous experience doing this, so any input on this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having more than 1 system installed on hdd don't affect computer performances.Also With 1gb of ram i would rather install other linux systems like mint,lubuntu or older ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!

Why is the older ubuntu better than the new one for 1GB of RAM?